# Where do I find the Batcave in Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

Does anyone know how to go to the Batcave in Batman Arkham City?
I am having trouble finding it on my xbox360.

Answer (score 7):

The Batcave is not available through regular gameplay because Wayne Manor is not located inside the Arkham City area.
However, you can play it as a challenge map in one of the DLC.

[Source](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batcave_(Batman:_Arkham_City))